# Do you have to respect safeareainsets on iOS apps?

Tags: swift, safearealayoutguide

Curious if safeareainsets have to be used or if they are just a guideline.

Our team had noticed that apps with lower bars (tab bar for example) will always respect this area, but list type apps (Apple's own contacts app) extends below the swipe up indication to the bottom.

The HIG document is not clear on these use cases, curious if anyone has solidified this concept.

Comment: You use them when it makes sense for any given view in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elements like the home bar or the notch could be considered as overlays. The safe area defines the portion of the screen that has no overlays over it.

You shouldn't expect your users to interact with content that is underneath one of these overlays, or outside the safe area, that's why navigation or tab bars are so respectful of these.

However, scrolling content can go outside the safe area because the user is able to simply drag it back into the safe area, that's why you see that many apps that don't have a tab bar will have their content go outside.